# word/term: to wear the same outfit as someone else (in public)

Tags: phrase-requests

I think there's a specific word/term for this but I can't seem to remember what it is: I'm trying to translate 撞衫 from Chinese in to English - one source defines it as:

> to wear the same outfit as someone else (in public)

while another says:

> two people wearing the same outfit by coincidence, causing embarrassment at social events

Chinese material insists on calling it a **clash**

[China.org.cn Learning English](http://www.china.org.cn/learning_english/2010-08/31/content_20832972.htm) says:

> 误译：When this actress was walking on the red carpet, she found her outfit clashed with another film star.
>
> 解释：to clash 的意思是to look ugly when put together，即“不协调”、“不搭配”。没有“撞衫”的意思。如：
>
> Outfit clashes are taboo to movie stars.

It doesn't seem that any English references really corroborate this, though.

Is there a good term for this?

Comment: Clash means two things do not go together, usually colors. For example, if one model (on a runway) is wearing shorts and another model is wearing an evening dress, they outfits could be said to be clashing. Or one actress wearing light pink and another wearing dark yellow.

Comment: Right, that's why I was saying that the "English references really corroborate"

Comment: Did you mean to post this on our sister site for [ell.se]? I ask because you use the abbreviation ***sb***, which is not one use by native speakers at all, only something found in materials for [ell.se].

Comment: @tchrist it was just in my dictionaries - hope I don't need to go to ELL as it is my 1st language

Comment: I'm not aware that there is a single English word for wearing the same outfit as someone else.

Comment: Magazines and TV shows often make fun of celebrities who wear the same thing, but I don't think I've ever heard them use a word to refer to it. They just ask questions like "Who wore it best?"

Comment: If there is a famous instance where this happened, maybe an expression could be formed from that?

Comment: Try **[clothing dopplegangers](https://fashionista.com/2014/03/kate-middleton-wedding-coat-missoni#!)**: *...there's really no best-dressed competition when your clothing doppelganger has two princes for accessories.*

Answer (score 2):

**Twinsies!** (interj., millennial slang) - This is a word millennials say when they are wearing the same piece of clothing, jewelry, etc. as the person they are talking to. Usually, you would only say this if you are happy to match someone else, but you could say it sarcastically if you are annoyed.

Twinsies also works as a plural noun - "We are twinsies today."

See [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/twinsies)

Now I remember that the verb form of this is "twinning". When two people are wearing the same clothes, they can say, "We are twinning!".

Also, the word **copycat** could work. Or to **steal** someone's outfit.

Comment: +1 I added a source and a link.  The source agrees with your definition, but not exactly.

Comment: @ab2 Lol, I can't believe Oxford had that.

Answer (score 0):

In my 62 years I’ve once noticed someone else wearing ‘my’ shirt and once ‘my’ jumper and two or three times seen women wearing the same outfits.

The shirt and the sweater guys found it mildly funny and all the women would rather have been somewhere else but none of them had a word for it and nor did anyone to whom we told our tales.

To me that suggests either we and our chums are rather ill-informed or no such word is in common use.

Comment: In uni halls, one guy I hung around with really liked my t-shirt (which was of a bloke in a tank saying "To the pub!"), and asked where I got it from. A few days later he was wearing the exact same shirt! It was *such* a distinct design that I stopped wearing mine for fear of embarrassment. I didn't stay friends with him either...

Answer (score 0):

From my answer At [Chinese StackExchange](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/26472/i-cant-find-the-equivalent-for-%E6%92%9E%E8%A1%AB-could-you-help/26475#26475)

> 撞衫: often used to describe movie stars, celebrity's who just happen to wear the same outfit

~

> '撞期'(date clash) means two events scheduled at the same date, creating a **scheduling conflict** between them. It is "(two scheduled events) dates run into each other" in English.
>
> '撞衫' (dress clash) means two people wearing identical outfits at the same event, creating a **fashion faux pas** for both. It is "(two people) dress the same" in English.

I suggest simply translate 撞衫 as "**dress the same**" or "**identically dress**"

For example:

- "安和瑪麗在頒獎典禮上**撞了衫**" (Ann and Mary **dressed the same** at the award show);
- "穿成衣可能導致與某人**撞衫**" (wear ready-to-wear dress many resulted in **dressing the same** with someone)